# Как сделать так на VueJS, чтобы при наведении на элемент, кнопка внутри него менялась

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Не знаю, как сделать такой эффект, рассчитываю на вашу помощь.[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Comment: CSS всё решается, псевдокласс :hover в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа:

```
.card-container:hover .btn {
  background: blue
}
```